# DataTables does not sort, when column data is from associated tables using server side processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

sort column data from associated tables using server side processing?

Railscast episode 340 allows to manipulate datatables in the server side but does not allow you sorting on associated table values

```
class Workshop < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :location, :class_name => 'Location'
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workshops
  attr_accessible :name,
end
```

Records are associated by id ( workshop.id = location_id)

On the Workshop datatable class, the information displayed is the location_name

```
class WorkshopsDatatable
  def data
    workshops.map do |workshop|
    {
      id:           workshop.id,
      location:     workshop.location_name,
    }
  end
end
```

I would like to be able to sort the location column by location_name and not by location_id.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Modify the line in your WorkshopsDatatable class as follows:

```
def sort_column
  columns = %w[id location_name]
  columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I am affraid that is not possible because the json rendering refers to the Workshops active record and not to the Location active record

```
<div class="well well-tzippy datatable-component">
  <table id="workshops" class="table-striped" data-source="<%= workshops_url(format: "json") %>">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th class="text-left">Title</th>
       <th class="text-left">Instructor</th>
       <th>Scheduled Time</th>
       <th class="text-left">Location</th>
       <th class="text-left">Contact</th>
       <th>Stats</th>

     </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
```

Notice that the data-source refers to the Workshop_path, so location_name is a column of the  table Locations associated with the Workshop active record by location_id= Workshop.id:

```
data-source="<%= workshops_url(format: "json") %>">
```